# How to Fix javax.net.ssl.sslexception connection closed by peer android

Tags: android

I am trying to get Json Data from "Movie DB" using "Volley" Library, but it show error like this "javax.net.ssl.sslexception connection closed by peer", so please help how to solve this problem...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    String uri = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=<MY_API_KEY>";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleid);
        loadtext();
    }

    private void loadtext() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, uri, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray resultArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                            JSONObject obj = resultArray.getJSONObject(1);
                            String name = obj.getString("title");
                            textView.setText(name);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        textView.setText("Error" + error);
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
         MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have api?

Comment: Yes  this is My api     "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=434fcadef5103207fecca9176385a533
"   please help me...waiting for your answers...

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Yes , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LLWhKon6P87YCbgJB--ArBI9Tr1TzOOP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you have any doubts about my code you can ask me

Comment: Bro I do not want to full code show me an only error file

Comment: you mean Logcat

Comment: No bro which activity show that error I want that code.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E7SKW_cyfcXQxAaWJ2ePsCaGk0Tvuw4P/view?usp=sharing]   you can have full mainActivity Code....

Comment: waiting for your answer....

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: no , waiting for your answer....

Comment: I am trying to get json data from **"Movies DB" Api** ,such as https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=434fcadef5103207fecca9176385a533,  but it shows error **"javax.net.ssl.sslexception connection closed by peer"**, and when i try another Api like **https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?page=1&page_size=50&site=stackoverflow
** it works fine , i don't know why it happens like that , i hope you will find answer to my question....

Comment: Are you comfortable with Volley Library?

Comment: yes , I am fine with these " VolleyLibrary ",   "Retrofit Library", and "Android Fast Network Library"

Comment: waitng for you reply..

Comment: can I give you a code with a volley library

Comment: yes, please....

Comment: If yes just give me the code of adapter

Comment: what is adapter , you mean Recyclerview Adapter code,

Comment: still i don't write Recyclerview Code...

Comment: yes because of Api response in array

Comment: so, you are trying to write an array response in a static text??

Comment: First, where are you check your API? and  second is write a recycler view for API after that any problem you are facing than ask to me

Comment: Before writing Recyclerview Code, I want to check whether the **"response"** is coming or not , and i just want display only **"Movie title"** , if it work fine, later i write Recyclerview Code..

Comment: My **MainActivity Code is above**, if you find any mistake ,Let me Know , and Waiting for your reply....

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine while you getting an error I am adding my code and define possible checks.

**CODE**

```
String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=434fcadef5103207fecca9176385a533";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("moive", "response: " + response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

**Permission Checks**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> If api level is 28 so add this

Inside application tag...

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answers,and I already added **"Internet Permission"**, and another thing is did you get **"Json Response"**  from Movie DB Api....

Comment: yes bro, For the answer, I am adding Logcat. Did getting your response via my code? Last, Did you add this `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: I thing problem was with my **"ACT FIBER BROADBAND CONNECTION "** it blocks some websites that why I did n't get any response from that **"Movie DB Api"**  and even that  website don't open in my browser, when I use **"HOLA VPN "** every thing works fine....I used **"VPN App"** in my Emulator than my App  works fine....

Comment: If you don't mind, I have another small App to develop, but i don't how to implement that. That is **How to implement Shared Element Acitivity Transition from RecyclerView Acitvity to ViewPager Activity without Fragments?**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753486/how-to-implement-shared-element-acitivity-transition-from-recyclerview-acitvity

Comment: Can you make small app  for me that is I want **"Shared Element Acitivity Transition from RecyclerView Acitvity to ViewPager Activity without Fragments"**....

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new Class "**MySSLSocketFactory**" and extends **SSLSocketFactory**
2. Copy and paste this code:

   ```
   SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

   public MySSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
       super();
       this.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
   }

   @Override
   public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
       return sslSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
   }

   @Override
   public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
       return sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
   }

   @Override
   public SSLSocket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
       SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);
       socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
       return socket;
   }

   @Override
   public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
       SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
       socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
       return socket;
   }

   @Override
   public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException,
           UnknownHostException {
       SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);
       socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
       return socket;
   }

   @Override
   public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
       SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
       socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
       return socket;
   }

   @Override
   public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort)
           throws IOException {
       SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);
       socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
       return socket;
   }
   ```

**3.** After that "`private void loadtext() {`"  in your code paste this:

```
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(context);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            sslContext.init(null, null, null);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
    }
```

**It worked perfectly for me after so much thinking.**

Comment: Hello @Ruben! Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you go through [how to write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It will heavily help you to avoid being down voted. I also suggest adding some details on snippet you're asking the OP to copy.